# Javascript, controlling an onbeforeunload tag

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to set up a onbeforeunload tag to stop a user from leaving specific pages if and only if they have unsaved content, and only on specific pages (we're using a single master page). I quickly discovered that having a return ##anything## in the onbeforeunload tag would always trigger a javascript confirm, and puts ##anything## inside the pop-up. Obviously, this is now expected behavior, but it does take away my idea of using my own confirm box that could be controlled with an if statement.

I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
<body class="yui-skin-sam" onbeforeunload="document.onFormClose();">

<script>
document.onFormClose = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('DirtyFlag').value == "true") {
        document.getElementById('DirtyFlag').value == "false";
        return 'You will lose all changes made since your last save';
    }
}
</script>
```

where DirtyFlag is a hidden field that turns true if any unsaved changes exist. I'd hoped that putting the return inside the function would do the trick, but no such luck.

So my question is, is there a way to use the onbeforeunload tag with a return built in that will bypass it pending the value of that field?
Alternatively, (though this would be less ideal) I suppose I could add or remove the onbeforeunload tag dynamically, in all the places I set or reset the getElementById tag. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that either.
Oh, and I'm restricted completely from using jQuery or any other javascript library.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want; the terminology you're using is a little off (there's no such thing as an "onbeforeunload" *tag*; it's an *event* that can be handled).  You cannot control the browser behavior very much - all you can do is get it to put up the confirm dialog.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is control whether or not the confirm actually appears. If I just leave the 'onbeforeunload' event in place, it will give me that pop-up regardless of if the user has unsaved data or not. And sorry about the wording, I've been bashing my head against this a little too long...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is as designed, but if you `return null` from the event handler, you *might* get the results you want:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("dirtyFlag");
    if (el.value === "true") {
        return 'You will lose all changes made since your last save';

    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

The following works in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/chZJ8/.  Try changing the hidden `input`s value to "true" and you should start getting the confirmation dialog.  **However**, I cannot get it to work in Chrome and I'm unable to test in IE.  It would be great if someone could confirm this works in either of those browsers.

**Edit:** Adding another example that's easier to use and works in Chrome (the iFrame in JSFiddle was causing issues).  Check out the example here: http://andrewawhitaker.com/examples/onbeforeunload_test.html.  Type 'true' in the input to see a confirmation.  If 'true' is not the value of the input, no dialog is displayed.  Works in FF and Chrome, still can't vouch for IE.

**Update 2:** A more reliable way of doing this is probably to add and remove the event listener when you set the value for `dirtyFlag` programmatically, just remove or add the event handler appropriately:

```
var isDirty = function() { ... };
if (/* form is dirty*/) {
    window.onbeforeunload = isDirty;
}
else {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Comment: Works on IE9. Better returning `undefined` than `null` but apparently buggy as the event appears to be raised twice

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the default behavior of `onbeforeunload`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I know I can't change the behavior, I'm trying to control whether or not it fires in the first place. I don't want to control it, I just want an on and off switch.