# javascript - Prevent page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want to prevent the page loading when "Editing" on m page occures.

so i got this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Now i need to unbind this from the page.

is there any methods available ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the handler to null:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

To unbind the event, set it to null:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

It may however be better for program flow to put a condition inside your `onbeforeunload` handler, so that you have a single function running on page unload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (myVar == "Editing") 
        return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use some flag to check if page is editing values or just navigating to other page

you can follow this thread too
[Javascript, controlling an onbeforeunload tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520819/javascript-controlling-an-onbeforeunload-tag)